# How to parse String having decimal, negative decimal into integer?

Tags: java, selenium

Under for loop i am getting string values like  decimal,integer, negative decimal values, i want to convert all of them in integer with one if condition,

how to achieve this?

```
 for(WebElement rowElement:TotalRowCount)
        {
              List<WebElement> TotalColumnCount=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td/span"));
              int ColumnIndex=1;
              for(WebElement colElement:TotalColumnCount)
              {
                  String s=colElement.getText().replace("%", "");

                  if(!s.isEmpty()&&!s.equals("NA"))
                  {

                   System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+" Column "+ColumnIndex+" Data "+s);

                  }
                  else{/*do nothing*/}
               }
              RowIndex=RowIndex+1;
         }
```

Comment: you want to convert decimal numbers to integers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: i dont know what string contains , it may conatin decimal, or integer, it is in loop i want if condition that should convert to integer

Answer (score 1):

```
int intnum= Integer.parseInt("1234");
```

See the Java [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) for more information.

(If you have it in a `StringBuilder` (or the ancient `StringBuffer`), you'll need to do `Integer.parseInt(myBuilderOrBuffer.toString()); instead).`

Comment: For more info https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00010.shtml

Comment: "_i am getting string values like decimal,integer, negative decimal values_" you will not parse everything with that code

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting decimals, then you can use `BigDecimal`.

```
BigDecimal nm = new BigDecimal(s);
int required = nm.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).intValueExact();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(WebElement rowElement:TotalRowCount)
        {
              List<WebElement> TotalColumnCount=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td/span"));
              int ColumnIndex=1;
              for(WebElement colElement:TotalColumnCount)
              {
                  String s=colElement.getText().replace("%", "");

                  if(!s.isEmpty()&&!s.equals("NA"))
                  {

                   System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+" Column "+ColumnIndex+" Data "+s);
         int val = (int) Double.parseDouble(s); // ==> This is val in integer

                  }
                  else{/*do nothing*/}
               }
              RowIndex=RowIndex+1;
         }
```

Comment: "_i am getting string values like decimal,integer, negative decimal values_" you will not parse everything with that code

Comment: Changed please verify

Comment: Off course I would mention  `java.lang.Math` class to be able to round based on OPs choice, using `Float` would even remove the casting (because `int Math.round(float)` ) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can check first that if a received String is numeric or not by the following method and put that method call as a condition in your if statement.

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String s) {
        if (s.isEmpty())
            return false;
        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So, your If condition in for loop should look something like `if(isNumeric(s)){...}`. Also, to parse these values only to the Integer you can cast them by `Math.floor(Double.parseDouble(s) + 0.5d)`. I think that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it above.

```
int result = 0;
```

As per your code ,

```
String s=colElement.getText().replace("%", "");
result = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Now result holds the integer value that you need to check.

Comment: "_i am getting string values like decimal,integer, negative decimal values_" you will not parse everything with that code.

Answer (score 0):

As your input may be decimal,integer, negative try below code to get proper rounded off result:

```
String s = "-88.4";
int a = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(s));
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: you could simply do `Math.round(Float.parseFloat(s))` to remove the casting here, I doubt you would get a difference between `double` and `float`.